# bfgminer using 100% CPU

Tags: mining-pools

I noticed that bfgminer is using 100% CPU on my Linux system even though it's using a Block Erupter ASIC.  Why is it using so much CPU? Is it possible to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

When using the [M] option in the console window and then using [+] to add devices you can type in "all" and this should select the ASIC USB Block Erupters and not the CPU. I had the same issue when I typed in "auto" which directs bfgminer to start looking for devices on your system to use for mining. Try doing [M] then [+] and typing "all" and then [Enter]